# trouble setting content-type on amazon s3 with carrierwave direct

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave, content-type

I have a rails app that successfully uploads product images to s3 using carrierwave and fog following the railscast tutorial.  Now I'm trying to use Carrierwave direct gem to upload the file directly to s3.  This works as well, except the content-type was set as binary/octet-stream which makes the images invoke a file download in the browser instead of just displaying the jpg.

So per the gem instructions at https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct, I added to carrierwave config:

```
config.will_include_content_type = true
```

And added a hidden field Content-Type with value of image/jpeg.

The file upload form generated by the form helper seems to be correct:

```
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" class="new_product_image_uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_product_image_uploader" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
    <input id="product_image_uploader_key" name="key" type="hidden" value="uploads/.../${filename}">
    <input id="product_image_uploader_aws_access_key_id" name="AWSAccessKeyId" type="hidden" value="...">
    <input id="product_image_uploader_acl" name="acl" type="hidden" value="public-read">
    <input id="product_image_uploader_success_action_redirect" name="success_action_redirect" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:5000/products">
    <input id="product_image_uploader_policy" name="policy" type="hidden" value="...">
    <input id="product_image_uploader_signature" name="signature" type="hidden" value="...">
    <input id="product_image_uploader_product_image" name="file" type="file">
    <input id="Content-Type" name="Content-Type" type="hidden" value="image/jpeg"><br>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Product image uploader">
  </form>
```

The base 64 encoded policy is:

```
{"expiration":"2013-06-21T13:35:42Z","conditions":[["starts-with","$utf8",""],["starts-with","$key","uploads"],["starts-with","$Content-Type",""],{"bucket":"mybucket"},{"acl":"public-read"},{"success_action_redirect":"http://localhost:5000/products"},["content-length-range",1,5242880]]}
```

Which appears to correspond with this article here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

But when I test it locally I get this error response in the browser:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: 
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]</Message>
...
</Error>
```

I don't really know what that means.  I googled for this error and found this issue: https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/issues/63

But the solution is not helpful.  Am I missing something?

I'm using:

carrierwave (0.8.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
    carrierwave_direct (0.0.12)

rails (3.2.13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling around some more, I found the following comment on this page: http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html

```
<!-- The file must be the last meaningful element in the request; other elements after this will be ignored -->
```

Switching the Content-Type hidden input field before the file input field fixes my issue.